# Problem in insert (UniqueIdentifier) in Table

Tags: asp.net, uniqueidentifier

Greeting,

I created my own database and used this method by Ankush Agnihotri (Create And Install ASP.NET Membership Database)to create users asnd membership and roles in my web application projects. See link below which method I used:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/create-install-asp-net-membership-database

I designed form to admin site to create an employee account in three steps :

First step :create employee account by (Registration tool) to create user account which will store employee account in Users Table.
Second Step: redirect admin  to next page to complete an employee form  information.
Until this moment a last two steps working correctly.
Third step: an confirmation appears to admin to catch a ROLE ID and USER ID which represented as (UniqueIdentifier) value to store its in USERSINROLE table as figures below:

[image: fig.1 message confirmation]

[image: Fig.2 table diagram]

A last two steps (one and two) working correctly, but a confirmation catch this problem:

[image]

My C# code behind to insert a two parameters in table, I tried in many ways from 1 to 5 but no ways to store a UniqueIdentifier value.

```cs
protected void Button1_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
  using (SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(connString))
  {
    sqlcon.Open();
    string query = "INSERT INTO UsersInRoles(UserId,RoleId) VALUES  (@UserId,@RoleId)";
    SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlcon);

    //Try NO.1
    //sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId",(FormView1.FindControl("l1") as Label).Text);
    //sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RoleId", (FormView1.FindControl("L2") as Label).Text);

    //Try NO.2
    //sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@UserId", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value=(FormView1.FindControl("l1") as Label).Text;
    // sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@RoleId", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value=(FormView1.FindControl("L2") as Label).Text;

    //Try NO.3
    //sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@UserId", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = new System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlGuid((FormView1.FindControl("l1") as Label).Text);
    //sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@RoleId", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = new System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlGuid((FormView1.FindControl("L2") as Label).Text);
                
    //Try NO.4
    //sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId",new Guid(Convert.ToString((FormView1.FindControl("l1") as Label).Text)));
    //sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RoleId", new Guid(Convert.ToString((FormView1.FindControl("L2") as Label).Text)));
                
    //Try NO.5
    //sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@UserId", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = new Guid(Convert.ToString((FormView1.FindControl("l1") as Label).Text));
    //sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@RoleId", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = new Guid(Convert.ToString((FormView1.FindControl("L2") as Label).Text));
                
    //Try NO.6
    sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@UserId", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier,32).Value =(FormView1.FindControl("l1") as Label).Text;
    sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@RoleId", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier, 32).Value = ((FormView1.FindControl("L2") as Label).Text);
    sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    FormView1.DataBind();
    sqlcmd.Connection.Close();
  }
```

So anyone able to help me. Thanks

Comment: Try to isolate the values extracted from the labels to separate variables. Then use the debugger to see what is the value in the variables and if something is not as expected. For example _var lab1 = (FormView1.FindControl("l1") as Label).Text;_

Comment: Thanks Mr. Steve; what you mean "Try to isolate the values extracted from the labels to separate variables"; are you mean separate (RoleId) and (UserId).  User Id and role Id values are separated basically ; My problems a label catch a role Id value. OK a problem unable to convert label value (string) to UniqeIdentifire;I followed many methods; but no way.

Comment: The error means that the value read from l1 or the value read from L2 or both are not present in the table Users or Roles. So set two variables with the value read from these two labels and use the debugger to check if the values are correct with the actual content of the users and roles tables

Comment: When you declare a column of type `uniqueidentifier` then you are supposed to supply the `GUID` to sql for that column. A valid `GUID` would be the ID of user in users table and ID of Roles in Roles table. I am not sure why would you have those values in textbox or in a label.

Comment: Hi Mr.@Steve if you read my code you can notice each value separated in two labels like below  sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@UserId", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier,32).Value =(FormView1.FindControl("l1") as Label).Text;
            sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@RoleId", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier, 32).Value = ((FormView1.FindControl("L2") as Label).Text);

Comment: Hi Mr. @JamshaidKamran thanks for your response: Actually, I designed a control panel to admin site  to managing a staff company depends on (Users Id and Role Id) as sample : I created eight roles, so when a site manager need to create new employee ( will add him with job role ), or change old employee role, as example: branch manager employee move to HR department). so when I use SQL tool to create security mode in my data base( membership, roles, etc) I use this method to change employee role depends to (User Id table) and (role Id table).I hope my idea was clear .Thanks